# Links not working with angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I've set up ui-router and I had it working a few minutes ago, sort of, it would display the template with content loaded from another html file, but none of the links would work.  Now nothing is working: the template shows up but the content is not pulled in and none of the links work.

**Ctrl.js**

```
var site = angular.module('site', ['ui.router']);

site.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('page', {
      url: '/page',
      templateUrl: 'page.html',
    })
    .state('about', {
      url: '/about',
      templateUrl: 'about.html',
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/page');
  })
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ctrl.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-app="site">

    <nav class="navbar  navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="navigate">
      <div class="container">

      <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navSmall">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navSmall">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#/about.html">about</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>


     </div>
    </nav>

  <div class="jumbotron text-center container-fluid">
    <div ui-view></div>


  </div>


<footer class="footer">
<div id="note" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
     -----Footer Content-----
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</footer>

  </body>
  </html>
```

**About.html (should be loaded but it's not)**

```
  <div ui-view="about">
    <div class="container-fluid bg-about">
      <div class="container-content">
      <div class="row">

      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Wow you all are fast!  Thanks for the suggestions.  So update: changing it to `ahref="#/about"` helped in that I can now go to the link but still no content displays.  There is a console error:

```
    Error: Access to restricted URI denied
fg/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:103:167
n@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:98:460
m/g<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:95:489
e/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:130:409
uf/this.$get</m.prototype.$eval@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:145:103
uf/this.$get</m.prototype.$digest@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:142:165
uf/this.$get</m.prototype.$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:145:399
Ac/c/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:21:115
h/<.invoke@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:41:374
Ac/c@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:21:36
Ac@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:21:332
fe@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:20:156
@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:315:135
g/</j@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js:2:29566
g/</k<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js:2:29882
 angular.min.js:117:399
```

Comment: Is `about.html` in the same directory as `index.html`? Also, you have `ui-view="about"` in `about.html` which would be something you would use with named views in child states but you don't appear to have any of those. Are you sure that's meant to be there? Finally, switch to the un-minified version of `angular.js` for better error messages while you're still developing

Comment: Are you by chance loading your app via the `file://` protocol, eg `file:///some/path/to/index.html`?

Comment: Is `<div ui-view="about">` required again in about.html if you are loading it in the parent `<div ui-view></div>` ? With the given navigation/router setup probably this is not required.

Answer (score 3):

Your state URL is `/about`, not `/about.html`.

In any case, use the [`ui-sref` directive](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/0.3.1/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref), that's what it's for

```
<a ui-sref="about">about</a>
```

You simply pass in the state name (and any params, see the documentation) and it will create the right URL for you taking into account any `$locationProvider.html5mode` configuration.

---

If you are loading the app via `file:///some/path/to/index.html`, the AJAX requests to your templates (ie `about.html`) might not work. You should be using an [HTTP server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) for your local development.

Have a look at (or even just clone as a base) the [angular-seed project](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed). It provides an excellent starting point for first-time Angular development.

Comment: Hey Phill, it seems that this is indeed the problem.  However, I recently developed a little two page app with ui-router and had no problems with it in either Chrome or Firefox so I'm puzzled about this.   I added the entire file path and it seemed to work.

Comment: @tfantina were you using `templateUrl` in that app? Perhaps you had set your browser to allow local AJAX requests or you were providing your templates inline, eg `<script type="text/ng-template" id="about.html">...</script>`

Answer (score 3):

You are mistake the state URL

your code `<li><a href="#/about.html">about</a></li>`

You can access the state by URL from browser, but referencing other section of the app is a **bad practice** though it still works

`<li><a href="#/about">about</a></li>`

**Do this**

```
<li><a ui-sref="about">about</a></li>
```

Answer (score 3):

your state URL is mistake, is /about not /about.html

Try this

```
<li><a ui-sref="about">about</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just make sure test.html be there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
            <script>
                var module = angular.module("sampleApp", ['ngRoute']);

                module.config(['$routeProvider',
                function($routeProvider) {
                    $routeProvider.
                        when('/route1', {
                            controller: 'myCtrl',
                            templateUrl: 'test.html'
                        }).
                        otherwise({
                            redirectTo: '/'
                        });
                }]);

              module.controller("MainController", function($scope) {

        });

        module.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
            $scope.my = 10;
            ab = function() {
                alert($scope.my);
            }
        });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body ng-app="sampleApp">
          <div ng-controller="MainController"> 
               <a href="#/route1" role="button">Route</a> 
                <ng-view>

                </ng-view> 
            </div> 
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @Phil : But what about if naturally it can be same ?

Comment: Yes i have edited it, because tfantina has used state concept in routing ;)

Comment: This seems to be part of the solution but it's still not passing in any content from other templates.

Comment: @tfantina : I have updated my answer, please try demo given

Comment: Hey Jingar, this demo looks good but it seems different because I believe it's using Angular's built-in ngRoute vs ui-router.   I've never used ngRoute would you recommend I use that?

Comment: Well i am using it currently, but ui-router is much latest than it, i would recommend you to use ui-router.

Answer (score 0):

For link to work you need to use

```
    <a href="#/about">about</a>
```

instead of

```
    <a href="#/about.html">about</a>.
```

Also for content to pull in like data binding you need to use controller.